# custom control not working in wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, silverlight

so right now we are changing from silverlight to wpf. The custom controls which were implemented for silverlight ,i am trying to copy them for wpf. The problem is The control is not visible in wpf.

Here is the implementation of the control:

The xaml file (c=CcsFeedbackLED.xaml):

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:controlls"
xmlns:vsm="clr-namespace:System.Windows;assembly=PresentationFramework">

<Style TargetType="local:CcsFeedbackLED">
    <Setter Property="EnabledColor" Value="Gray" />
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:CcsFeedbackLED">
                <Grid>
                    <vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">

                            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="GradiantOverlay"
                                        BeginTime="00:00:00"
                                        Duration="00:00:00.50"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                        FillBehavior="HoldEnd">
                                        <LinearColorKeyFrame 
                                            Value="#40000000" 
                                            KeyTime="00:00:00.50"/>
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="GradiantOverlay"
                                        BeginTime="00:00:00"
                                        Duration="00:00:00.50"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                        FillBehavior="HoldEnd">
                                        <LinearColorKeyFrame 
                                            Value="#5E000000" 
                                            KeyTime="00:00:00.50"/>
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="GradiantOverlay"
                                        BeginTime="00:00:00"
                                        Duration="00:00:00.50"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops)[2].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                        FillBehavior="HoldEnd">
                                        <LinearColorKeyFrame 
                                            Value="#00000000" 
                                            KeyTime="00:00:00.50"/>
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="GradiantGloss"
                                        BeginTime="00:00:00"
                                        Duration="00:00:00.50"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Ellipse.Fill).(LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                        FillBehavior="HoldEnd">
                                        <LinearColorKeyFrame 
                                            Value="#48FFFFFF" 
                                            KeyTime="00:00:00.50"/>
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="GradiantGloss"
                                        BeginTime="00:00:00"
                                        Duration="00:00:00.50"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Ellipse.Fill).(LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                        FillBehavior="HoldEnd">
                                        <LinearColorKeyFrame 
                                            Value="#CEFFFFFF" 
                                            KeyTime="00:00:00.50"/>
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </vsm:VisualState>
                            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="GradiantOverlay"
                                        BeginTime="00:00:00"
                                        Duration="00:00:00.1"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                        FillBehavior="HoldEnd">
                                        <LinearColorKeyFrame 
                                            Value="#B0000000" 
                                            KeyTime="00:00:01"/>
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="GradiantOverlay"
                                        BeginTime="00:00:00"
                                        Duration="00:00:00.1"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                        FillBehavior="HoldEnd">
                                        <LinearColorKeyFrame 
                                            Value="#CE000000" 
                                            KeyTime="00:00:00.1"/>
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="GradiantOverlay"
                                        BeginTime="00:00:00"
                                        Duration="00:00:00.1"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops)[2].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                        FillBehavior="HoldEnd">
                                        <LinearColorKeyFrame 
                                            Value="#70000000" 
                                            KeyTime="00:00:00.1"/>
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="GradiantGloss"
                                        BeginTime="00:00:00"
                                        Duration="00:00:00.1"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Ellipse.Fill).(LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                        FillBehavior="HoldEnd">
                                        <LinearColorKeyFrame 
                                            Value="#48FFFFFF" 
                                            KeyTime="00:00:00.1"/>
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="GradiantGloss"
                                        BeginTime="00:00:00"
                                        Duration="00:00:00.1"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Ellipse.Fill).(LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                        FillBehavior="HoldEnd">
                                        <LinearColorKeyFrame 
                                            Value="#CEFFFFFF" 
                                            KeyTime="00:00:00.1"/>
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </vsm:VisualState>
                        </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
                    </vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                    <ScrollViewer 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
                        IsTabStop="False"
                        Padding="0" 
                        Background="{TemplateBinding EnabledColor}">
                        <Grid Background="Transparent">
                            <Rectangle 
                                x:Name="GradiantOverlay"  
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                                <Rectangle.Fill>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,1" EndPoint="0,0">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#40000000" Offset="1" />
                                        <GradientStop Color="#5E000000" Offset="0.90" />
                                        <GradientStop Color="#00000000" Offset="0" />
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Rectangle.Fill>
                            </Rectangle>
                            <Ellipse 
                                x:Name="GradiantGloss"
                                RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0"
                                Width="Auto"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                                <Ellipse.Fill>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#78FFFFFF" Offset="1" />
                                        <GradientStop Color="#EEFFFFFF" Offset="0" />
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Ellipse.Fill>
                                <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                                    <TransformGroup>
                                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1.75" ScaleY="0.65" />
                                    </TransformGroup>
                                </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                            </Ellipse>
                        </Grid>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The code behind File (CscsFeedbackLED.cs):

```
    using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Ink;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace controlls
{
    using Harris.BCD.Toolkit.Silverlight.Controls.Utilities;

    /// <summary>
    ///     A simple LED Control with a customizable color
    /// </summary>
    [TemplateVisualState(Name = VisualStateInfo.StateNormal, GroupName = VisualStateInfo.GroupCommonStates)]
    [TemplateVisualState(Name = VisualStateInfo.StateDisabled, GroupName = VisualStateInfo.GroupCommonStates)]
    [ImplementsControlEvents]
    [InheiritedControlEventsAction(typeof(Control), "IsEnabled")]
    public class CcsFeedbackLED : Control, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region Dependency Property Definitions

        /// <summary>
        ///     Color Dependency Property
        /// </summary>
        public static DependencyProperty EnabledColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "EnabledColor", typeof(Brush), typeof(CcsFeedbackLED),
            new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(CcsFeedbackLED.OnColorPropertyChanged)));

        #endregion
        #region Data Properties

        /// <summary>
        ///     The color of the LED, specified in Hexadecimal form:
        ///     Format: #DDRRGGBB
        ///         DD - Opacity (00-FF)
        ///         RR - Red Channel (00-FF)
        ///         GG - Green Channel (00-FF)
        ///         BB - Blue Channel (00-FF)
        /// </summary>
        [ControlEventsAction]
        public Brush EnabledColor
        {
            get { return (Brush)GetValue(CcsFeedbackLED.EnabledColorProperty); }
            set { SetValue(CcsFeedbackLED.EnabledColorProperty, value); }
        }

        #endregion
        #region Object Construction

        /// <summary>
        ///     Default object constructor
        /// </summary>
        public CcsFeedbackLED()
            : base()
        {
            this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(CcsFeedbackLED);      // Register the Style Key

            this.IsEnabledChanged += delegate(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                this.UpdateVisualState();
            };
        }


        /// <summary>
        ///     Registers named child controls when a template is applied.
        ///     Also responsible for registering data-contexts for data bindings.
        ///     *** DO NOT INVOKE DIRECTLY ***
        /// </summary>
        public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            base.OnApplyTemplate();

            this.UpdateVisualState();
        }

        #endregion
        #region Object Methods

        /// <summary>
        ///     Updates the Visual State of the Control
        /// </summary>
        protected virtual void UpdateVisualState()
        {
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, (this.IsEnabled) ? VisualStateInfo.StateNormal : VisualStateInfo.StateDisabled, true);
        }

        #endregion
        #region Control Events

        /// <summary>
        ///     Generic Property Change event, fired whenever a dependency property is changed
        /// </summary>
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        /// <summary>
        ///     Notify when a property changes
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="propertyName">The Name of the Property Changed</param>
        protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        #endregion
        #region Control Event Handling

        /// <summary>
        ///     Event fired whenever the color property changes
        ///     ** DO NOT INVOKE DIRECTLY **
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        protected void OnColorChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged("EnabledColor");
        }

        #endregion
        #region Static Property Dependency Handling

        private static void OnColorPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            CcsFeedbackLED objChange = d as CcsFeedbackLED;

            if (d == null)
                return;

            objChange.OnColorChange(e);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

And i am try to use it in a wpf Application by referenceing the above project as follows:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:he="clr-namespace:controlls;assembly=controlls"
        Title="MainWindow" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch">

    <Grid>
        <he:CcsFeedbackLED

                                            Margin="-44,-96,10,31"
                                            EnabledColor="#FF00FF00"
                                            IsEnabled="True" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

But i am not able to see the control when i run the application?
Is there some quickFix for this? This problem is probaly the result of copy the control directly from silverlight to wpf

Comment: Are you able to debug and place a breakpoint within the controls initialization code? Does it reach that breakpoint? Is there a breakpoint that does not get hit along the execution path?

Comment: well when i try. Its hitting all the breakpoints.

Comment: Is the setting of `Margin="-44,-96,10,31"` causing it to not display properly?

Comment: tried correcting it.. did not work

Comment: Where did you assign the Resourcedictionary? Inside the App.xaml as Application Resource? Or is it inside an external Assembly that you are loading during start?